# mousedown is not calling my function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've created links to transition yet when the function is supposed to be called using the onmousedown event I get an uncaught undefined function. Clearly my function is defined. I'm am still learning code so what is it I don't see or understand. Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
var url = "phpajaxtut.php";
});
function swapContent(cv){

    $("#myDiv").html("animated gif goes here").show();

    .post(url, {contentVar:cv}, function(data){

        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();

    });


}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con1')">Click the text</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con2');">Click the text</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con3');">Click the text</a>
</head>
<body >

<div id ="myDiv">My default content</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.post` is a syntax error. Did you mean `$.post`? Also, your `url` variable it outside the scope of your `swapContent` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `$.click();` instead, since you're already using jQuery, and forgo the hyperlinks? You can easily style some spans to look like `a`s if that's what you want. My example just updates some text, but in there you can place / call your function.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfvn4/):

```
// html
<span>Click Me</span>
<br />
<span>Click Me</span>​

// js
var n = 0;

$("span").click(function(){

    $(this).text($(this).text() + " " + n++);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a $ before .post?

```
$.post(url, {contentVar:cv}, function(data){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var url = "phpajaxtut.php";
});
```

The var url isn't global. It can only be used inside the function

```
var url; //global url

$(document).ready(function (){
    url = "phpajaxtut.php"; // set global url
});
```